# Prevent iframe from rendering if source server is down

Tags: jquery, iframe, dynamic

We would like to offer a widget with content from our website to third-party websites in the form of an iframe.

`<iframe src="http://oursite.com/iframe"> </iframe>`

**In the occasion that our website is down or in maintenance mode, we don't want the iframe to render at all as this will result in a page-not-found message on the host's website.**

To achieve this, we want the iframe to be embedded dynamically after checking that our server (oursite.com) responds with a 200 status.

To make this "check" process as lightweight as possible we created a url `http://mysite.com/status` that returns an empty response body. The response status will always be 200, unless the server is down or in maintenance mode.

**Question-1**: What is a javascript (plain/jquery) code sample that can be placed on the host's website to make the request to `http://oursite.com/status` and get the response status (so that we can then decide to append the iframe tag to the document or not)?

**Question-2**: Is this the best way to achieve the goal which is to prevent the iframe from rendering if oursite.com is down?

Comment: Is it garunteed that jQuery is included in the third-party websites? if it isn't, do you really want to include the entire jQuery library just to send an ajax request? Note that you'll have cross-domain issues too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using javascript, create an image element and load an arbitrary image from the target domain. Use the onload event of the image element to show the iframe. If the image never loads, the iframe never gets shown.

```
(function($) {

    var img = $('<img/>');
    img.on('load', function() { /* show iframe */ });
    img.prop('src', 'http://www.example.com/my.gif');

})(jQuery);
```

There is no need for a separate status url using this method. This is a very lightweight method to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 1):

Create the iframe using a `<script src="http://mysite.com/mysitewidget.js"></script>`. If the script can't be retreived due to your server being down, no iframe will be created. (it will slow down the user's site though while it waits for said script to timeout.)